# Websocket how to receive two request chatgpt at the sametime

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, python-asyncio, chatgpt-api

I have a websocket (in Django) to receive request from client (reactjs). The request calls chatgpt api to stream its response to client.

```
class GPTAPIConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print('Start', data['requestID'])
        asyncio.create_task(self.streamToClient(data['requestID']))

    async def streamToClient(self, requestID):
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(...)
        content = ''
        for chunk in completion:
            if chunk['choices'][0].get('delta', {}).get('function_call'):
                chunkContent = chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['function_call']['arguments']
                if chunkContent is not None:
                    content += chunkContent
                    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'text': content}))
        print('End', requestID)
```

From client, I sent two messages with requestID 1 and 2. In server, the request 1 took about 10 seconds to finish so the log is:

```
Start 1
End 1
Start 2
End 2
```

What I want is:

```
Start 1
Start 2
End 1 or End 2 (depends which one ends first)
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it work by making the openai api call async:

```
completion = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(...)
content = ''
async for chunk in completion:
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're facing is that the `streamToClient` function is awaiting the completion of each request before moving to the next one. To achieve concurrent processing and interleaved responses for multiple requests, you can leverage asyncio's `gather` to run tasks concurrently. Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
class GPTAPIConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print('Start', data['requestID'])
        asyncio.create_task(self.streamToClient(data['requestID']))

    async def streamToClient(self, requestID):
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(...)
        content = ''
        async for chunk in completion:
            if chunk['choices'][0].get('delta', {}).get('function_call'):
                chunkContent = chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['function_call']['arguments']
                if chunkContent is not None:
                    content += chunkContent
                    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'text': content}))
        print('End', requestID)

# You can use asyncio.gather to run tasks concurrently
async def run_multiple_requests(request_ids):
    tasks = [GPTAPIConsumer().streamToClient(request_id) for request_id in request_ids]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

# Example usage:
request_ids = [1, 2]  # List of request IDs
await run_multiple_requests(request_ids)
```

This code will execute the `streamToClient` method for each request concurrently using `asyncio.gather`. It should allow the responses to interleave and not wait for one request to complete before processing the next one. Adjust it to fit within your Django setup and utilize the necessary components.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your point but don't know how to integrate it, because the request 1 and 2 don't come at the same time, how could I create two tasks then gather them like in your code? Thank you

Comment: @TrongLamPhan you should probably ask ChatGPT, where this user got the "answer" from.